# How can I get mod_rewrite and mod_alias to work together?

Tags: windows, apache, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

I have a Windows/Apache/PHP environment set up to imitate a shared hosting account but cannot get `mod_alias` and `mod_rewrite` to play nicely with one another. Both are definitely enabled at the server level and on a per-site basis.

I have `d:\web\public_html\` set up as DocumentRoot. But generally speaking it will be empty.

I have `d:\web\sites\` which is where I'll be storing my sites and pointing to using `Alias` and it has the following directory structure beneath it:

```
d:\web\sites\alfa
d:\web\sites\alfa\public_html
d:\web\sites\bravo
d:\web\sites\bravo\public_html
```

I have aliases set up as follows: (and they definitely work!)

```
Alias /alfa d:/web/sites/alfa/public_html
<Directory "D:\web\sites\alfa\public_html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The `public_html` folder(s) are where my per-site `.htaccess` files are stored and they definitely have `mod_rewrite` enabled but won't work correctly.

So far I have come unstuck with what `RewriteBase` should be. I've tried `/`, `/alfa`, `/alfa/` and `alfa/`. I've even tried `d:\web\sites\alfa\public_html`, `d:/web/sites/alfa/public_html`, `d:\web\sites\alfa` and `d:/web/sites/alfa` to no avail!

Is this even possible? If so, what am I doing wrong?

I'd obviously like to keep my `Alias` directives centralised and by `RewriteRule`s in per-site `.htaccess` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the

```
AllowOverride None
```

directive and thus disabling any `.htaccess` files in the aliased directory.
Remove that, and it should work.

`/` should work for `RewriteBase`.

Comment: Straight from my httpd.conf: <Directory "D:/web/public_html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Comment: @Matt so the code you are quoting in your question is not the correct one?

Comment: Thankyou!! I have my aliases in a seperate file to httpd.conf and I hadn't spotted it in there! Thank you so much!

Comment: For reference though, I'm using `RewriteBase /alfa` so that my rules don't have to be prefixed with `/alfa`. Is that the correct usage/purpose of `RewriteBase`?

Comment: @Matt ah, I overlooked that you are in a subdirectory. Yes, that *should* work (although `RewriteBase`'s behaviour has always been a bit of a mystery to me, in some situations working for me, and sometimes not... Maybe I'll ask about it on SO some time.)